# How to download an image - no image file given

Tags: html, download

I would like to download a logo from a webpage. The problem is that there is no url to the image file such as a `.png`, `.gif` or `.jpg`.

[image]

How to find the path to the logo? The path highlighted after clicking on the logo (see the above screenshot) gives an empty image.

[image]

How to add the colour?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the image is a Scalable Vector Graphics (svg) image, not a png or gif.  In the debug tools you have open, you can right-click and copy the entire  element and save it in a file with the .svg suffix.   You'll be able to open the .svg file with a photo viewer, or if you need it in a different format, there are online utilities that can convert .svg to .png (or whatever) for you.

For example, the LinkedIn logo in their app bar is

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M20.5 2h-17A1.5 1.5 0 002 3.5v17A1.5 1.5 0 003.5 22h17a1.5 1.5 0 001.5-1.5v-17A1.5 1.5 0 0020.5 2zM8 19H5v-9h3zM6.5 8.25A1.75 1.75 0 118.3 6.5a1.78 1.78 0 01-1.8 1.75zM19 19h-3v-4.74c0-1.42-.6-1.93-1.38-1.93A1.74 1.74 0 0013 14.19a.66.66 0 000 .14V19h-3v-9h2.9v1.3a3.11 3.11 0 012.7-1.4c1.55 0 3.36.86 3.36 3.66z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: I updated my question: 1) the logo is black and white - how to add the colour; 2) where did you find the path in the debug tool?

Comment: @Viesturs questions should not be updated to make a followup question, instead post a new question on a site where the question be on-topic. To ask for a site a recommendation post a question in [meta.se].